# bg color not showing in bootstrap

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a website from scratch, and for the life of me i cant figure out why this code won't accept BGCOLOR in the body header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 17 Jan 2017 15:47:26 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body BGCOLOR="#013adf">

</body>
</html>
```

it seems that the line 
     `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

is whats preventing it from loading? i don't know why though.

Comment: bgcolor is obsolete and shouldn't be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bgcolor` attribute is not supported in HTML5 (which is what you've declared by default with your DOCTYPE declaration at the top).

Easiest thing to do is use CSS instead.

Inline CSS.

```html
<body style="background-color:#013adf">
<p>Your content goes here</p>
</body>
```

Seperate CSS File

```css
body{
  background-color:#663399;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Your content goes here</p>  
</body>
```

Comment: No problem Please consider marking it as an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (once the 15 minute lockout period is over)